# math.h functions in fixed-point (32,32) format (64-bit) library for C

Tags: math, static-libraries, math.h

I'm looking for a 64-bit fixed-point (32,32) library for one of my C implementations.

Similar to this one http://code.google.com/p/libfixmath/

Need support for standard math.h operation.

Did anyone see such implementations?

Comment: asking for library suggestion is off-topic here. You should go to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

`fixedptc` seems to be what you look for. It is a C, header-only and integer-only library for fixed point operations, located at http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/fixedptc

Bitwidth is settable through defines. In your case, you want to compile with `-DFIXEDPT_BITS=64 -DFIXED_WBITS=32` to get a (32,32) fixed point number format.

Implemented functions are conversion to string, multiplication, division, square root, sine, cosine, tangent, exponential, power, natural logarithm and arbitrary-base logarithm.